# Multiple target prediction for a Regression Problem

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am doing my master's thesis on Indoor positioning system using BLE rssi. I have prepared a dataset with 4 features (rssi values from 4 ble rssi scanners). Target columns are x-coordinate and y-coordinate.

I want to predict both x and y coordinate at the same time. I can't find a way to do that. Crrently what I am doing is making 1 model for predicting x-coordinate and doing same for y-coordinate. The problem here is that model is learning y-coordinate better with MSE close to 1.5 while in learning x-coordinate the MSE is 2.5.

The regressors that i am using are: Linear Regression, kNN regressor, SVM regressor and random forest regression.

How can I have 1 model for both x and y and then single MSE using both x and y?

Comment: Would this work for you: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540123/muti-output-regression-in-xgboost ?

Comment: @Grzegorz yes, finally that worked. Thanks for help